# How we can check QA Review issues on Magento Marketplace?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, extensions, marketplace

I have upload extension on Magento marketplace and its Rejected from QA Review. As we can check only Technical Report where showing No verification errors. Can you guys please suggest how we can get the QA Issues so I can fix and re-upload from the review.

Thanks

Comment: You can find QA issue report in your registered mail with attached screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Is your problem solved as my extension is failed in QA.

Comment: No, its really difficult to reproduce Magento 2 QA issues

Answer (score 2):

Please email marketplace@magento.com with any Marketplace submission problems. They'll be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Magento marketplace launch new support panel for ticket https://marketplacesupport.magento.com/hc/en-us  From here you can create a support ticket to ask your question and you will also find more Info regarding Magento Marketplace.